# How to ignore stopwords in txt file and count the number of words and eliminate punctuation, using python?

Tags: python

I am trying to implement my code, to index a corpus, however I keep getting an error and not sure where I am going wrong, here is snippet of the code. Thanks for any help or guidance.
the error is    reduced = filter(lambda w: w not in stopwords, re.split(r'\W+', words.lower()))
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'lower'

```
#within your program ignore any term that matches a stop word.
#Creating .txt file with stopwords and thereby creating a routine in which stopwords are ignored and counting the number of words


    stopwords = open(r'C:\User\Desktop\cacm\stopwords.txt',"r")
    words = open (r'C:\Users\Desktop\cacm\cacm\index.dat',"r")
    reduced = filter(lambda w: w not in stopwords, re.split(r'\W+', words.lower()))
    counts= Counter (reduced)
    print list ( reduced)

    #Ignore any term that begins with a punctionary character
    # Ignore any term that is a number 
    cleaned_text = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', "C:\Users\Desktop\cacm\cacm\index.dat")
    # Ignore any term that is 2 characters or shorter in length  
    shortword = re.compile(r'\W*\b\w{1,2}\b')
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be a good idea to post the error you are getting?

Comment: I have posted the error, thanks for any guidance

Comment: The error is obvious from the message: file objects don't have a `lower` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open function returns a file object, not a string list. If you want to obtain the list of lines from the text file, you can use the readlines() method on the file object. However, it may be more efficient to iterate the text file processing one line at a time. It is up to you.

On the other hand, even if *words* is a string list, it doesn't have a lower() method. You need to iterate through it calling the lower() method on each element of the list.

Remember also to close the file objects once you are done with them.

You can do something like this:

```
file = open("stopwords.txt")
stopwords = file.readlines()
file.close()

file = open("index.dat")
words = [word.lower() for word in file.readlines() if not word.lower() in stopwords] #assuming a word per line
file.close()
```

You can include additional processing like removing punctuation symbols in a similar way, either in the same expression on it different expressions. It depends how compact you want your code to be versus how many passes are you willing to do through the data.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. How would I write the results to an outputfile, I know you can  write some thing outputfile = open('C:\Users\Desktop\cacm\outputFile.txt',"w")
outputfile.write( words)
outputfile.close() however I am getting the error, TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

Comment: @user3133032 it is because you need to combine the elements in the list into a single string for write() to work. You can join the strings with a separator, for a example a newline if you want a string per line, using the join() method for strings. You can do something like this: output.write("\r\n".join(words)). Even if Python is dynamically typed, paying attention to type errors gives you a lot of information about runtime problems.

Comment: Thanks again  I appreciate your help btw, any suggestions on how I would count  the number of stop words which match and the number of words remaining. I am thinking using Counter, but not sure how to implement.

Comment: You're welcome! A Counter is like a dict with counts as values. You can iterate through your list updating the corresponding entry in the Counter, and at the end you will have the number of occurrences of each individual element. Alternatively, if you already have your list filtered, you can just substract its length from the length of the original list to have the total number of matching stopwords.